# Javascript call event when create content HTML

Tags: javascript

This's my code:

```
    // main.js
    var component = {
       create: function() {
          var element = document.getElementById('app');
          element.innerHTML = this.render(); 
       },
       render: function() {
          return '<button onclick="this.showMessage">Click me!</button>';
       },
       showMessage: function() {
          alert('Hello world');
       }
    };
    component.create();
```

and in index.html

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

When i run this code and click to button, nothing to happen. I want when click to button, browser will show a dialog with message "Hello world!", how can i do that? Somebody can help me? Thank so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

First, you need to put `()` after a function to call the function, so it should be `showMessage()`.

Second, in an `onclick` handler, `this` is the button you clicked on, not the object. You need to refer to the variable containing the object, `component.showMessage()`.

```js
var component = {
  create: function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('app');
    element.innerHTML = this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    return '<button onclick="component.showMessage()">Click me!</button>';
  },
  showMessage: function() {
    alert('Hello world');
  }
};
component.create();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not parsed in any particular JavaScript call context, so `this` will not refer to your object; it will refer to the DOM element that was clicked.  In other words, you can't (easily) do what you are asking by using `innerHTML` unless you use global variables, and there is no need to use global variables here.  (Further, you don't invoke the `showMessage` function, you just refer to it.)

You could create the element using the DOM API instead:

```
var component = {
    create: function () {
        var element = document.getElementById('app');
        element.appendChild(this.render());
    },

    render: function () {
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click me!'));
        btn.addEventListener('click', this.showMessage.bind(this));
        return btn;
    },  

    showMessage: function () {
        alert('Hello world');
    }   
};  
component.create();
```

[See it run](https://jsfiddle.net/4srwr7Lp/)

You could also use a library like jQuery to make DOM manipulation easier.

```
var component = {
    create: function () {
        $('#app').append(this.render());
    },

    render: function () {
        return $('<button>')
            .text('Click me!')
            .click(this.showMessage.bind(this));
    },  

    showMessage: function () {
        alert('Hello world');
    }   
};  
component.create();
```

[See it run](https://jsfiddle.net/4srwr7Lp/1/)